# How do I prove that it takes at most $3$ cuts to divide a $n$ by $m$ chocolate bar up into any ratio? (cocoacoalition)

Tags: number-theory

I'm currently doing a competitive programming problem ([cocoacoalition](https://open.kattis.com/problems/cocoacoalition)) from the NCPC 2019 contest.

In it, we're asked to find the minimum number of splits to divide an $n$ by $m$ chocolate bar into $a$ and $nm - a$ pieces.

> Alice and Bob decide to share a chocolate bar, which is an n by m rectangular grid of chocolate cells. They decide that Alice should get a<n⋅m pieces and that Bob should get b=n⋅m−a pieces. To split the chocolate bar, they repeatedly take a single piece of chocolate and break it either horizontally or vertically, creating two smaller pieces of chocolate. See Figure 1 for an example.
> [image]
> What is the minimum number of splits that Alice and Bob need to perform in order to split the n-by-m chocolate bar into two piles consisting of a and b chocolate cells?

> Figure 1: Illustration of a solution to Sample Input 2, showing the original 10-by-10 chocolate bar split three times into pieces of size 10-by-2, 10-by-5, 3-by-3 and 7-by-3. Giving Alice the 10-by-5 and 7-by-3 pieces, she gets a total of 50+21=71 chocolate cells.

The [solution to the problem](https://nordic.icpc.io/ncpc2019/ncpc19slides.pdf) (slide 34) claims you need a maximum of three splits to accomplish this. In the case where $n|a$ or $m|a$, you only need one split. If not, if $a$ can be factored into $xy$ for some $x,y \leq min(n,m)$, you only need two splits.

However, it goes on to claim that $3$ splits are enough for any value of $a$.

How would I go about proving this statement? Trying to phrase the idea of the third split mathematically, I want to prove that $a$ can always be written as any of $xy + kn$, $xy + km$, $xy + k(n-x)$, or $xy + k(m-y)$, but this feels clunky somehow?

Is there a better way of formulating this so that I can prove it better?

Comment: Can you please revise your question to not include as many external links. Mathjax format is preferred, and images, as a last resort. Also, include your previous attempts.

Comment: Isn't  it just making 2 "horizontal" cuts with a one row cut joining them? If the rows are n blocks across then divide a by n. The dividend is the number of rows and the remainder is the number of blocks in the partial row.

Comment: @Laufen hey, sorry for that! i've rewritten it to make it a bit more informative. also added some of my "attempt" but its a bit hard because i'm not really sure how to even phrase the idea mathematically

Comment: @Peter oh god you're right. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transcription of the slide:

> Solution
>
> 1. One split suffices if $a$ is divisible by $n$ or $m$.
> 2. Two splits suffice if $a$ can be factored into $a=x \cdot y$ where $x \leq n$ and $y \leq m,$ or if $n \cdot m-a$ can. (Check by trying all $O(n)$ possible values of $x .)$
> 3. Three splits are always enough.

I suppose the first point is sufficiently clear. For the second point, you're cutting off a block of size $x\times y$ from one of the corners of the bar.

For the third point, we can now assume that $a$ is not divisible by $n$. Thus
$$ a = kn + r$$ where $r<n$ and $k< m$ (If $k\ge m$, then $a=kn+r\ge nm+r>nm$.)
You can therefore use one cut to make a $k\times n$ block and a $(m-k)\times n$ block. From this second block, you can use two cuts (by step 2) to make a $1\times r$ block.
Now give Alice the $k\times n$ and the $1\times r$ blocks.